# 2 overlapping as3 flash buttons, both need click functionality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Flash banner that uses a shell to subload a `swf` file.

The shell contains a movieclip that covers the entire `swf` as a clicktag button.

The subload has a seperate call to action button. I need both of them to be clickable and dispatch seperate events.

Normally I would drag the cta button over the clicktag but because the clicktag is in the shell and the cta button in the subload I can't do that.

How do I get both buttons to be clickable in this structure?

I would like have the clicktag event defined in the shell and the cta button event defined in the subload.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know the animation sequence of the banner Im not sure this will help you, but instead of a normal button you can use `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClicktagFunction)` to add the listener directly to the flash stage. This way the whole container banner (including subloads) will trigger `myClicktagFunction` when a user clicks over it.